# Dividing regions of a plane by lines

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

At most how many regions can be divided by 10 lines on a plane?

This is not homework, this is from a math competition.

I figured out by drawing a picture that with 2 lines I can split the plane into at most 4 regions, with 3 lines I can split the plane into at most 7.  I am having trouble generalizing for more lines because there are a lot more possibilities.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000124

Comment: Hint: For any line n you add you get n additional areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, the answer is sum of the n sequence + 1: ${n}{(n+1)}/{2}+1$. For 1 you get 2, for 2, 4 and for 3 you get 7, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  But I'm still confused why that gives the max number of regions.

Comment: The reasoning is as follow: every time you cross a line you add a partition. The first partition starts in the starting point in infinity and after that n-1 lines are crossed, to a total of n partitions added by the n's line.

Comment: Thank you again.  Is this right?  To make the max number of regions possible, make sure no 2 lines are parallel, and make sure thru every point there are $\leq$ 2 lines going thru that point.

Comment: This seems to be correct.